# Checking when an object, function or element is ready

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'd like to have a generic use function to pass a dynamically created object as parameter and run a callback function when the object is ready without jQuery. The object should be either a global function, HTML element or plain global object.

In the example below, I create objects dynamically but they are never found after they are created dynamically. I understand I am passing a reference to a non-existent object which is never found in a checker loop. But what I want is exactly what I have below - check when either function, object or HTML element exists and run a callback.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      !function() {
        var interval = 1000,
            timeout = 30000;

        var onElementReady = function(obj,callback){
            console.log('onElementReady '+obj)
            //obj=window.dynamicFunction;
            var elementChecker = setInterval(function () {
                console.log('object exists? '+obj)
                if ('undefined' !== typeof obj) {
                    clearInterval(elementChecker);
                    callback();
                }
            }, interval); 
        };

        var init = function(){
            console.log('Element is found!')
        };

        onElementReady(window.dynamicFunction, init);
        //onElementReady(document.getElementById('test2'), init);
        //onElementReady(myObject, init);
    }();

    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log('adding dynamicFunction');
        dynamicFunction = function(){};
    }, 10000);

    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log('adding global object myObject');
        myObject = {foo:'boo'};
    }, 5000);

    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log('adding test2');
        document.getElementById('test1').id = "test2"
    }, 5000);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="test1"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to pass a string to the function.  Otherwise, it will continuously test for `undefined`.

Within the function, you could test for the object's existence within `window` using bracket notation.

You could test for dynamically-created elements with IDs using `document.getElementById`:

```js
var onElementReady = function(obj, callback) {
  if(window[obj] || document.getElementById(obj)) {
    if(typeof window[obj] === 'function') {
      window[obj]();
    }
    if(callback) {
      callback();
    }
  }
  else {
    setTimeout(function(){
      onElementReady(obj, callback)
    },1000);
  }
} //onElementReady

onElementReady('newfunc');

onElementReady('newelement',
  function(){alert('New paragraph created!')}
);

onElementReady('globvar',
  function(){alert('New global variable:\rglobvar = '+globvar)}
);

var newfunc = function() {
  alert('It lives!');
}

document.body.innerHTML= '<p id="newelement">Some paragraphs are dynamic.</p>';

setTimeout(function() {
  globvar = Math.random();
},2000);
```

Comment: I like this approach as well. One thing is I wish I could pass HTML element as an object instead of ID string. Is it possible?

Comment: I think you'd need to use `eval` for that.  But if you provide an example, there may be another solution.  (Note that I've updated the answer using your function name instead of `poll`.)  Interesting question!

Answer (score 1):

Pass func as string

```
onElementReady("window.dynamicFunction", init);
```

Then use eval to check if the function actually exists:

```
var onElementReady = function(obj,callback){
           console.log('onElementReady '+obj)
           //obj=window.dynamicFunction;
           var elementChecker = setInterval(function () {
                console.log('object exists? '+obj)
                //eval("var check = typeof "+obj  );
                eval("var check = "+obj+" && typeof "+obj  );

                if ('undefined' !== check) {
                    clearInterval(elementChecker);
                    callback();
                }
            }, interval); 
        };
```

**EDITED** Maybe this works now

Comment: Very interesting approach. Thanks. Is eval safe enough for usage though? I heard a few issues before.

Comment: eval should always be avoided server side, but client side.... yes, i ve heard that is evil, but think about this... i can edit javascript code on browser and execute, so you shouldn´t worry for this

Comment: This wouldn't work here: onElementReady("document.getElementById('test2')", init); because getElementById returns an object somehow